# confused about dictionary created variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
states = {
    'oregon': 'OR',
    'florida': 'FL',
    'california': 'CA',
    'new york': 'NY',
    'michigan': 'MI'
}

cities = {
    'CA': 'san francisco',
    'MI': 'detroit',
    'FL': 'jacksonville'
}

cities['NY'] = 'new york'
cities['OR'] = 'portland'


for state, abbrev in states.items(): # add two variables
    print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (state, abbrev)

print '-' * 10    
for abbrev, city in cities.items():
    print "%s has the city %s" % (abbrev, city)

print '-' * 10
for state, abbrev in states.items():  # this is what i'm confusing about
    print "%s state is abbreviated %s and has city %s" % (state, abbrev, cities[abbrev])
```

I just want to know on the questionable line, there are only two variables inputed(state & abbrev), why there could be three variables quoted(state & abbrev & cities[abbrev])?

My guess is that 'abbrev' is being used twice, once in states dict and once in cities dict. So cities[abbrev] means to return the second value of each paired things? Can someone please confirm if my guess is correct?

If that's the case, why do I get a keyerror when I change cities[abbrev] into cities[state]? The error code is: KeyError: 'california'. It should return the first value of each pair.

I am confused on how this is working, can you please help me find a way out?

Comment: That line is using the value of `abbrev` to get a value from the previously defined `cities` dictionary.

Comment: the value of `states` is a key in `cities`. `state` is not a key in `cities`.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, `states.items()` iterates of the key-value pairs, e.g. ('oregon', 'OR'). `state` will be `'oregon'` and `abbrev` will be `'OR'`. What `cities[abbrev]` does is finding the value of `'OR'` in the dictionary `cities`. In the case of `'OR'` that is `'portland'`.

If you tried a value that is not in the keys of the dictionary, e.g. `banana`, then Python would throw a `KeyError` because the value `banana` is not a key in that dictionary.

To ensure that a key is present in a dictionary, you can use the `in` operator.

```
for state, abbrev in states.items():
    # if the value of abbrev (e.g. 'OR') is a value in the cities dictionary
    # we know that there is a city in this state. Print it.
    if abbrev in cities:
        print "%s state is abbreviated %s and has city %s" % (state, abbrev, cities[abbrev])
    else:
        print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (state, abbrev)
```

Comment: so you mean that the abbrev in cities is the result of abbrev in states dict? so it's just like: cities[OR], to find the value of OR? and that's why it occurs keyerror because that the state in states dict is not in cities dict either in key or in value. is my understanding correct? @Bram Vanroy

Comment: Yes, exactly. But `abbrev in cities` only checks if that value is in the dictionary *as a key*. It doesn't check whether it's in the values. If you want to check if it's a value, you can do `abbrev in cities.values()`.

Comment: and one more question: if I use abbrev in cities.values(), then it will return the key rather than the value, right? @Bram Vanroy

Comment: ... No. `cities.values()`: get the *values*, `cities.keys()`: get the keys. `cities.items()` get the key-value pair.